# Union two tables with partially overlapping column and returning rows with non-null column values if exists

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join, union, coalesce

I have following table in postgres 11. I am joining following two tables using 'union'

Table1

```
col1    col2        col3    col4            
4894775 NCT00000172 drug    galantamine     
4894772 NCT00000174 drug    rivastigmine    
4895618 NCT00000241 drug    flupenthixol
```

Table2

```
col1    col2        col3    col4            col5            col6
4894775 NCT00000172 drug    galantamine     galantamine     {N06DA} 
4895618 NCT00000241 drug    flupenthixol    flupenthixol    {N05AF}
```

I would like to have the two tables joined such that whenever col5 and col6 are not null then pick those rows else pick the null rows.

I have tried following query so far:

```
select distinct on (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
                    col1, 
                    col2, 
                    col3, 
                    col4, 
                    coalesce(b.col5, a.col5), 
                    coalesce(b.col6, a.col6),  
             from (
SELECT
                    col1, 
                    col2, 
                    col3, 
                    col4, 
                    null as col5, 
                    null as col6
from table1 a
 
union
 
select              col1, 
                    col2, 
                    col3, 
                    col4, 
                    col5, 
                    col6
from  table2 b
order by col1
```

The desired output is:

```
col1    col2        col3    col4            col5            col6
4894775 NCT00000172 drug    galantamine     galantamine     {N06DA} 
4894772 NCT00000174 drug    rivastigmine    (null)          (null)
4895618 NCT00000241 drug    flupenthixol    flupenthixol    {N05AF}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a `left join`:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, t2.col5, t2.col6
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 using(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

If there may be "missing" rows in both tables, then you can just change the `left join` to a `full join`.